# Office 2019 going crazy when pressing Alt+Shift, to change language from English to Hebrew

Tags: microsoft-office, input-languages

When I'm pressing Alt+Shift in Word or Excel to change language from English to Hebrew, the following thing is happening:

[image: Screen shot showing the problem]

Its looks like only the Alt key being registered.
Why this problem happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key-combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is handled by Windows and not
by Word or Excel.
It changes the system **keyboard layout** and not the language in the document,
but Word or Excel will set the language automatically.
This affects *every program* on the computer.

Under Windows 10 you will need to choose your language from a pop-up that will appear
on the side of your screen. This is equivalent to clicking the "Eng" in your
traybar and choosing Hebrew.

If this does not solve your problem, please describe it in greater detail.